# Update to Azure diagnostics: rolestatus and get health status

Tags: azure

So I would like to know what the updated disgnostics are for RoleStatus and getHealthStatus() in Azure ?

Thanks
Supraja J

Comment: Updated compared to what? What exactly are you looking for? A changelog?

Comment: Apparently as part of the Nov 2010 release, role status/manager is gone since Microsoft.ServiceRuntime is deprecated and now this functionality is provided using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics. But I was'nt able to figure out which ones equal the old RoleStatus' functionality.

Answer (score 0):

From: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.roleinstancestatuscheckeventargs.aspx

```
public override bool OnStart()
{
   RoleEnvironment.StatusCheck += RoleEnvironmentStatusCheck;
   return base.OnStart();
}

private void RoleEnvironmentStatusCheck(object sender, RoleInstanceStatusCheckEventArgs e)
{
   Trace.WriteLine("The status of the role instance: " + e.Status, "Information");
}
```

See also:

RoleInstanceStatusCheckEventArgs.SetBusy(): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.roleinstancestatuscheckeventargs.setbusy.aspx

and

RoleEnvironment.RequestRecycle(): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.roleenvironment.requestrecycle.aspx